# Test database is flushed despite `--reuse-db` being specified

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

As per the [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#reuse-db-reuse-the-testing-database-between-test-runs):

> Using `--reuse-db` will create the test database in the same way as `manage.py` test usually does. However, after the test run, the test database will not be removed. The next time a test run is started with --reuse-db, the database will instantly be re used. This will allow much faster startup time for tests.

This actually doesn't work and is not true:

Here's `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myproject.settings
addopts = --reuse-db
```

and here's `django_db_setup`

```
import sqlite3
import uuid

import pytest
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management import call_command


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_user():
    return {
        'username': uuid.uuid4().hex[:10],
        'password': uuid.uuid4().hex,
    }


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup(django_db_blocker, test_user, django_db_keepdb):
    db_path = settings.BASE_DIR / 'test-db.sqlite3'
    sqlite3.connect(db_path.as_posix())
    settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = db_path
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        call_command('migrate', '--noinput')
        User.objects.create_user(
            username=test_user['username'],
            password=test_user['password'],
            email=f'{test_user["username"]}@test',
            is_active=True,
        )
```

and `django_db_keepdb` evaluates to `True`. Here's the tests:

```
def test1(django_user_model, django_db_keepdb):
    print(django_db_keepdb, django_user_model.objects.all())


def test2(django_user_model, django_db_keepdb):
    print(django_db_keepdb, django_user_model.objects.all())
```

which results in:

```
True <QuerySet [<User: b18cd8369b>]>
True <QuerySet []>
```

and the expected results are

```
True <QuerySet [<User: b18cd8369b>]>
True <QuerySet [<User: b18cd8369b>]>
```

So, how to actually obtain this outcome?

Comment: in Django, by default database create when test run and destroy automatically, I don't think so we can keep it as save and reuse it again, there is a flag --keepdb but I don't know how to get it