# How to run django runserver in a background thread?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing, pytest-django

I need to run django `runserver` in the background to enable tests with `selenium` and `pytest`. A similar [functionality](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#live-server) is provided by `pytest-django`'s `live_server`. But using `live_server` [flushes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771867/test-database-is-flushed-despite-reuse-db-being-specified) the database after each test which implies recreation of tables and migrations on each test which is redundant and unacceptably slow. My main objective is to create a database and test user, login with selenium once and run all tests which is clearly impossible using `pytest-django`'s `live_server`. As per the [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#reuse-db-reuse-the-testing-database-between-test-runs:%7E:text=you%20need%20to%20repopulate%20your%20database%20every%20time%20a%20test%20starts%2C%20because%20the%20database%20is%20cleared%20between%20tests):

> you need to repopulate your database every time a test starts, because the database is cleared between tests

and there is no way around it. So the solution is to run a django server in the background and use it instead. Here's a couple of approaches:

**Using a thread:**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from threading import Thread

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


def start_server(src):
    os.chdir(src)
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', f'{Path(src).name}.settings')
    os.environ['DB_NAME'] = 'test_db.sqlite3'
    get_wsgi_application()
    call_command('migrate')
    call_command('runserver')


def run_server(src):
    thread = Thread(target=start_server, args=[src], daemon=True)
    thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server('/path/to/myproject-root')
```

which results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 15, in start_server
    call_command('runserver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 198, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 673, in run_with_reloader
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *args: sys.exit(0))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/signal.py", line 56, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

So, I tried using a process instead:

```
process = Process(target=start_server, args=[src], daemon=True)
```

which is not working unless I remove `daemon=True` but then I'm unable to terminate / kill the process without killing the IDE.

One workaround with a thread is to modify `call_command` to:

```
call_command('runserver', use_reloader=False)
```

The server starts successfully but whenever I try accessing it, I get a 400 response.

Comment: Can you simply run a server in one terminal instance and perform your checks in another at the same time?

Comment: I want to automate it because I don't want to have to do some manual work each time `pytest` is invoked.